# How do i change property of nested object in State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

state looks like this for example

```
{
  ownRecipe: {name:""}
}
```

now i need to change name property, this doesn't work

```
this.setState({ownRecipe[name]:"Pineapple pizza"});
```

this works, but maybe there is a better way?

```
let ownRecipeCopy = {}
for(let key in this.state.ownRecipe){
  ownRecipeCopy[key] = this.state.ownRecipe[key];
}
ownRecipeCopy.name = e.target.value;
this.setState({ownRecipe: ownRecipeCopy});
```

Edit: thanks everyone for your answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spread the original object and change the property you want:

```
this.setState(prevState =>({
    ownRecipe : {
        ...prevState.ownRecipe,
        name : 'new name'
    }
}));
```

Comment: Due to the async nature of setState, it is not advisable to use `this.state` to get the previous state within `setState`. Instead, always rely on passing a callback `this.setState(prevState => ({ownRecipe : ... }))` when updating the state with a previous state value. prevState received by the updater function is guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with prevState. see [react-setstate-usage](https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60) and [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: true. fixed! Thank you

Comment: see also [setState is asynchronous](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-setstate-a4640451865b)

Comment: Only you have to put `...prevState.ownRecipe` instead, otherwise it puts copy of the whole state into ownRecipe object.

Answer (score 3):

Access the property like so:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ownRecipe: { ...prevState.ownRecipe, name: "Pineapple pizza" }});
```

The spreading saves the previous contents of the object, so you don't lose any other information. You could also do it like this:

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, ownRecipe: { ...this.state.ownRecipe, name: "Pineapple pizza" }});
```

But this gets tedious if you have lots of properties.

Comment: the first `...prevState` is not necessary, react will merge the objects for you, `this.setState(prevState => ({ ownRecipe: { ...prevState.ownRecipe, name: "Pineapple pizza" }});`